# Telegram sports club bot architecture

Tags: architecture, telegram-bot

I'm designing a telegram bot architecture for a local sports club. It offers group and individual training sessions with coaches.

A user must be able to:

- see all of the upcoming training sessions info (including the list of trainees who signed up for the session already);
- pay for a single session or multiple sessions at once (subscription);
- sign up for a session (after successful payment or using a previously bought subscription).

An administrator must be able to:

- add, edit and delete training sessions;
- sign up a user for the training session (no payment);
- remove a user from a session's trainee list;
- change user's subscription (add or remove sessions).

That's the basic functionality the bot must provide. Admin's interface is under discussion, all of the actions may be done via bot's telegram interface or via some database GUI in the brouser for starters.
Bot language is Java, because I'm not ready to learn Python just yet. There **should not be much load**, very little in fact, and the amount of stored data doesn't seem too big.

Now for the question: **how do I choose the database** for the task?

In my search I've come across SQLite, it seems lightweight and easy to use but would it be enough? There wouldn't be a gui available AFAIC, so I'd have to implement admin commands via the bot from the start, which means more development work until the bot is usable. Or should I use more advanced DBs like Postgres? It can be accessed via VPS provider's browser gui, so that's a plus, but is it worth it as it would require an additional server? However, there probably will be new features later like getting statistics for the admin or new types of trainings so the database would have to keep up with the changes.